# Create dinamically tables based on slicer selection DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've a calculated table created based on measures and I want filter this table based on a slicer selection from original table. Following the original table:

| Team | Points | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | new york |
| A | 5 | las vegas |
| A | 3 | san francisco |
| A | 7 | miami |
| B | 8 | new york |
| B | 11 | las vegas |
| B | 14 | san francisco |
| B | 8 | miami |
| C | 17 | new york |
| C | 30 | miami |

Here are the measures:

```
total_a = CALCULATE(SUM('team_base'[Points]),FILTER('team_base',Team = "A"))
total_b = CALCULATE(SUM('team_base'[Points]),FILTER('team_base',Team = "B"))
total_c = CALCULATE(SUM('team_base'[Points]),FILTER('team_base',Team = "C"))
```

And the calculated table was builded as follows:

```
agg_team = {("Total A",[total_a]),("Total B",[total_b]),("Total C",[total_c])}
```

The output:

| Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| Total A | 19 |
| Total B | 51 |
| Total C | 47 |

However, I want filter the city, for instance by "new york" and get the desiree output:

| Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| Total A | 4 |
| Total B | 8 |
| Total C | 17 |

I know it's possible do it using SELECTEDVALUE function but I'm new in power bi and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Calculated tables are calculated at refresh time and that's it. They aren't re-calculated during report interaction.  Is there a reason why you need a Calculated Table?

Comment: Yes, because when I put the values in calculated table format it allows me create a bar chart with space between the bars, different of when I simply drag the measures to a cluster bar chart.

Comment: I want a trick that could be used to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments - "Calculated tables are calculated at refresh time and that's it. They aren't re-calculated during report interaction."

For your scenario, you don't need any measures or calculated table. Simply add `'team_base'[Team]` to the Y-axis and `'team_base'[Points]` to the X-axis and you'll get the chart you are after with slicers working.

[image]